# Shading regions in ParametricPlot

Tags: graphics, filling

I am using `ParametricPlot` to get an `X` vs `Y` plot. I want to shade the area enclosed by the curve falling in the region where `Y<0`.

For example, how to shade the area enclosed by the `Sin` curve where `Sin[x]<0`?

```
ParametricPlot[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: If you're just plotting $y=f(x)$, it's simpler to use `Plot[]` with its `Filling` option...

Answer (score 8):

```
 ParametricPlot[{ u, If[Sin[u] < 0, v, 1] Sin[u]},
   {u, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1},
   AspectRatio -> 1, Mesh -> False,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[.8]]]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{ u, If[Sin[u] < 0, v, 1] Sin[u]},
 {u, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1},
 Mesh -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Hue[v]], 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

**Update:** Few alternatives that use `{u, v Sin[u]}` as the first argument of `ParametricPlot`:

Using `ColorFunction`:

```
ParametricPlot[{ u, v Sin[u]}, {u, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1},
AspectRatio -> 1, Mesh -> False,
ColorFunction -> (If[Sin[#1] > 0, White, Red] &),
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Using `Mesh`, `MeshFunctions` and `MeshStyle`:

```
ParametricPlot[{u, v Sin[u]}, {u, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   Mesh -> {{0.}},
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, u, v}, y]},
   MeshShading -> {Red, White},
   PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Comment: All these solutions are extremely slow in case if you have a time-consuming function instead of `Sin[u]`. Timing is much smaller if the second variable `v` is dropped and no filling is made.

Answer (score 6):

You could do:

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, Sin[x]}, {x, y}}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, Min[0, Sin@x]}, 
               Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Using `Plot[]` is much easier

```
Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, {Yellow, None}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As always, credit to Heike for her `torn[]` magic, and to Szabolcs for his super-hyper image uploader palette

Comment: `torn[]` - tearing apart all context and courtesy by unasked for boldness, since no idea when! Thank you for the visual harassment I guess ^^

Answer (score 5):

Evaluation is faster than Verde's solution plus this little deviation close to the intersection is gone: Make a second plot of y `Min[Sin[x],0.0]` with y as an additional variable, so you can use the mesh to fill the area.

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, Sin[x]}, {x,y Min[Sin[x],0.0]}},
                 {x, 0, 2 Pi }, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, Mesh -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it does not work perfectly, e.g. for a filling sin(x)<0.1.

Comment: Sadly I don't have enough reputation to post an image.

Comment: I did it for you ... now you have some rep

Comment: Hi! welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this answer are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time you will be able to do more on the site (post graphics, edit things, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to collect some more points now :)