# Shading an area enclosed by a loop

Tags: plotting, scripting, wolfram-alpha-queries

I am plotting the folium of Descartes as a parametric plot, and trying to find the arclength and the area enclosed by the loop. I got both of them covered result-wise, but my professor wants us to shade the area enclosed by the loop, and bold the arclength(the whole loop). I have been trying to figure that out for quite some time now but just can't seem to get it to work.

1. One way I found out you can do that is by using RegionPlot[] and fill the parameters. In my case nothing is shaded just my plot is being printed. [Link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html)
2. I found this question on here [Link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9945/shading-regions-in-parametricplot) but I didn't find it helpful, because some of the solutions include Filling which is not available for ParametricPlot[]

My code:

```
x[t_] := (12 t)/(1 + t^3)
y[t_] := (12 t^2)/(1 + t^3)
```

Vertical tangent lines

```
dir = {0, 1};
sol = Solve[Det[{{x'[t], y'[t]}, dir}] == 0, t, Reals];
```

Plot with the "shaded area" that doesn't work

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Folium of Descartes", 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]], 
 RegionPlot[
  ParametricRegion[{x[t], 
    y[t]}, {{t, 0, Infinity(*sol = 0.793701*)}}], 
  PlotStyle -> LightBlue, BoundaryStyle -> None]]
```

It also wouldn't accept `sol` as an argument. I could be wrong but I think I am supposed to integrate from t = 0 to t = Infinity and not t = sol (0.739...) right?

As for the bolding part of the graph I was thinking about just using Style and Bold for an interval of values for t where they make a loop. Would that work?

Any kind of help is appreciated
Thank you!

Comment: It is impossible to find such loop since only when `t->Infinity`, the parametric curve go back to `{0,0}.  `Limit[{x[t], y[t]}, t -> Infinity]`

Comment: Yeah after playing around with this for some time I noticed that. ```Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize -> .05, Point[{x[t1], y[t1]}]}], {t1, 0, 
  0.739}]``` Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
pp = ParametricPlot[{ x[t], y[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
  PlotPoints -> 400, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  MeshFunctions -> {# #2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshShading -> { Automatic, Green}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

```
Normal @ pp /. {Green, l_Line} :> 
    {l, Polygon @@ l, Black, 
     Text[Style[Row[{"arc length: ", ArcLength@l}], 14], {1, 9}, Left],
     Text[Style[Row[{"area: ", Area[Polygon @@ l]}], 14], {1, 7.5}, Left]}
```

[image]